# Setting a filter loses the next user input

Tags: ms-access, vba

In MS-Access 2010, I have a tabular form with a text field, which I want to use as a filter for the data presented. When the user enters a value in this field, in its event handler, I set the form's filter and filteron properties. All is well, except that one user input (the klick or keypress with which she leaves the filter control) is lost - that is, she has to tab or click twice to leave the field. She finds this most annoying.

I experimented with all events on the text box - either it doesen't work, or it eats one user input.

See the attached [example database](http://ebruenner.de/download/FilterClick.accdb) - after typing a filter value in the filter box (say the character 'c'), click on the lower box (some other control). On that click, the filter is properly applied, but the cursor remains in the filter box. It moves only after a second click to the other control.

How can I avoid loss of that user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this behaviour before, but can't remember if I found a good solution (probably not, or I'd remember).

A decent workaround is to separate the two things:

1. Move focus to a different control, triggering Control_AfterUpdate
2. Apply filter

by using the `Form_Timer` event procedure.

`Me.TimerInterval = 1` activates the timer, and `Me.TimerInterval = 0` deactivates it.

```
Private Sub SetFilter()
    Me.Filter = "tText >= '" + Nz(Me.FilterMin) + "'"
    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub

Private Sub FilterMin_AfterUpdate()
    ' Separate control navigation and filtering by using the Form.OnTimer event
    Me.TimerInterval = 1
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Timer()
    ' Deactivate timer (important!)
    Me.TimerInterval = 0
    Call SetFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess that's it. Thanks for your idea :)